# JavaScript 8-bit floating point

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point

To start, I am in the wrong language and I think it is time learn some C++ and compile it as an add-on for NodeJS. For now, though, I have a few code snippets that work that may be interesting or may be an abomination of coding.

This code works with weather forecast data, specifically the GRIB-2 file format. GRIB-2 compresses weather information into either integers or floating point values depending on the type (this cast is wind gusts). The data has been packed into 8-bit floating point values. I am assuming the GRIB-2 protocol follows floating point arithmetic and we can break our 8-bits into the following sections: `0 000 0000`

Code to convert hex: 26 to floating-point: 0.6875:

```
var bin = makeWhole('100110'); //hex: 26
var fp = nBitFloatPoint(8, bin); //8 is unused but will allow different bit lengths

console.log(fp) // 0.6875

function makeWhole(a){
  var hex = a;
  if(hex.length !== 8){
    hex = prepend(hex);
  }
  return hex;
}


function prepend(hex){
  var diff = 8 - hex.length;
  var str = '';
  for(var i=0; i<diff; i++){
    str += '0';
  }
  return str + hex;
}

function nBitFloatPoint(n, bin){

  var s = bin.charAt(0);
  var e = parseInt(bin.substring(1, 4), 2) - 3;
  var m = '1.' + bin.substring(4, 8);
  var d = shiftDot(m, e);
  var result = convert(s, e, d);

  return result;

}

function convert(s, e, d){

  var strD = d.toString()
  var length, dotIndex, num, frac;
  var values = [];

  length = strD.length;
  dotIndex = strD.indexOf('.');
  num = strD.substring(0, dotIndex).split('');
  frac = strD.substring(dotIndex + 1).split('');

  //console.log(num)
  for(var i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    if(parseInt(num[i])){
      values.push(Math.pow(2, i));
    }
  }

  for(var i=0; i<frac.length; i++){
    console.log(frac)
    if(parseInt(frac[i])){
      //console.log(Math.pow(2, -i))
      values.push(Math.pow(2, -i-1));
    }
  }

  if(values.length){
    return values.reduce(arraySum);
  }
  return 0;
}

function arraySum(prev, curr, index, arr){
  return prev + curr;
}

function shiftDot(m, e){

  var str = '00000000000000000000000000' + m;

  var dot = str.indexOf('.');
  str = str.replace('.', '');

  return parseFloat(str.substring(0, dot + e) + '.' + str.substring(dot + e));
}
```

Is this a really hack idea that is best left to a language mean to work with binary buffers? Is the function `shiftDot` a plausible workaround or am I missing something best left to an internal JS function?

Comment: I upvoted earlier, but I'm afraid I now had to vote to close. After looking at this more closely, this appears to be hypothetical code, which is [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CodeReview. Besides a couple of actual errors in the code (extra single quote, missing close-brace), it currently doesn't actually do a full conversion. So from a review standpoint there's little to do, because it's not finished. But if you have more complete code that does the full conversion, feel free to post it.

Comment: updated with working code

Comment: And I've retracted my close vote. However, I'm not sure about your conversion. As far as I can tell, [from reading a little](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat), 8-bit floats express integer values (range -122880 to 122880 with poor precision), not fractional values. So I get a value of `122` from `0x26`.

Comment: How to split the binary string is an issue. The protocol I am converting (`GRIB`) does not state how it is split but I know that in this example there must be a decimal because wind speeds of `122 m/s` or `272 mph` isn't feasible at sea-level. I was basing my conversion off [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691199/floating-point-conversion-for-8-bit-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Having looked at it again, I'm back to my original conclusion: It's broken. Not because of the string parsing itself (although that's most likely broken as well), but because everything before the parsing is broken: `makeWhole(0x26)` returns 38. The number 38. Not a string, and certainly not a binary string. So everything from that point on will only make it things worse. It's quite surprising it actually returns anything resembling a float at the end.

Comment: Actually, for all the 256 possible values between `0x00` and `0xFF`, your code will only output 4 different "floats": `[ 0.125, 0.5, 0.25, 0.59375 ]`. No idea how you ever got the `0.6875` that's in the code.

Comment: I created an error when copying code to CodeReview. Passing a hex-code into a function that is expecting a js style representation of an 8-bit binary string. makeWhole(a) is meant to prepend the missing Zeros to the front of the string that JS so conveniently removes for us.

Comment: Ok, but running your most recent code (I saw you just edited), it logs `0.375`. Still not what your comment says. Now you're just calling `makeWhole` with a number (`100110`) which is a base-10 number - still not a binary string.

Comment: Ya, again with the copy paste. It is a string now and working on my end as it should. Sorry for confusion and posting something different here than on my end.

Comment: And I'm sorry to say that if I pass every possible `0x00`-`0xFF` value - now properly stringified and padded - I still only get 80 unique values out. None of them negative, by the way, though that's what the high-bit should signify. It's not following a logical progression either.

Comment: If there is a high bit the string going into the function chain will already be 8-bits long and therefore be negative. However, with some testing you have just proven that wrong. Thank you for pointing on the flow issues as that clearly made this more difficult than it should have been. The last error you have found is further in the code. I will try to find how to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

To start I know nothing about GRIB-2 that being said I know some ways that you could improve your code.

**"Magic Numbers"**

Generally you shouldn't put numbers in code where their meaning is unknown. You should set the hanging numbers to constants. Javascript (ES5) doesn't have constants but there are ways to fake it. The number "8" in your code is abstract and one would only know what it is for because you told them. But a without that it would be hard for anyone to know what it means from an initial read through of your code.

Possible Solution - You could create a constant object literal.

```
var Constants = {
  FLOAT_BIT_LENGTH: 8
}
console.log(Constants.FLOAT_BIT_LENGTH);
```

**Polluting the Global Namespace**

As it goes right now your code is putting a bunch of functions and variables into the Global namespace. You should encapsulate your code in a self invoking function, so you can set variables that are global to your code without foo-ing with the global variable scope, if you want other people to be able to embed your code as a module in someone else’s code.

Possible Solution - Self invoking anonymous function to create scope

```
(function (document) {
 /* code goes here */
})(document);
```

**Non-Descriptive Variables and Parameters**

You should be able to read the method signature and know what it does. convert(s, e, d) means nothing to anyone even knowing what the code is for. You could add documentation blocks via JSDocs, and make your function variables more descriptive.

Possible Solution - JSDocs used along with descriptive function arguments

```
/**
 * Converts a foo into a foobar using bar as the radix and baz as the offset
 * @param {integer} foo - Does x
 * @param {integer} bar - Does y
 * @param {float} baz - Does z
 * @return {float} - x AND y AND z
 */
convertByRadix(foo, bar, baz)
```

**Not Making Use of Function Expressions in Callbacks**

Function expressions can be used as a callback function, they are inline and make your code easier to read when the function is only a line or two and have no side effects. Also you don't need to declare all the parameters of a callback, only the ones you are using.

```
return values.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr;
});
```

It may also be worth looking into typed values (that are not boxed) that are available in some Javascript compilers/libraries, like "ASM.js" or "LLJS". As well as looking into possibly using some of Javascripts bitwise operators. Also look into running your code through a linter such as JSHint.